# Power BI : If a date from a table is between a start date and a end date from another table without relationship

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need your help and skills.
It's been a while i'm blocked.

In Power BI, I have to perform a transformation on one of the tables, T_BACKLOG.

I'm trying to get the name of the sprint in which the issues were created.
In table T_BACKLOG I want to add a custom column (SPRINT_NAME) to get the Sprint's name from R_SPRINT.

**Please find more details below :**

***MODEL :*** Tables without relationship

**R_SPRINT contains** :

- the name of the Sprint (NAME)
- the start date of the sprint (START_DATE), French formart.
- and the end date of the sprint (END_DATE), French formart.

**T_BACKLOG contains** :

- The ID of the issue (ID)
- The title of the issue (TITLE)
- The creation date of the issue (CREATION_DATE)

**The expected result T_BACKLOG "extended"** :

- The ID of the issue (ID)
- The title of the issue (TITLE)
- The creation date of the issue (CREATION_DATE)
- SPRINT_NAME : Custom column that has to contain the right sprint name regarding the creation date of the issues compared to the start and the end date of the sprints.

**THE LOGIC** :
Based on the creation date of the issue in T_BACKLOG, find the right sprint in table R_SPRINT regarding the start date (START_DATE) and the end date (END_DATE) of the Sprints.

[image: R_SPRINT]

[image: T_BACKLOG (With the custom column SPRINT_NAME)]

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Gamus

Comment: Shouldnt CDA-5 be part of CDA Sprint Pl 1.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution using Power Query:

Step 1: Duplicate the R_SPRINT table and enable its load. This is how it should looks like.

[image]

Step2: Use the following power query code in the duplicated table.

Note: remember you have to adapt the code bellow to your case.

```
let
    //All your previos Steps. Remember to change "Changed Type" in the next row for your last step name.
    #"Inserted Date Subtraction" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "DATE_RANGE", each Duration.Days([END_DATE] - [START_DATE]), Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Date Subtraction", "DATE", each List.Dates([START_DATE],[DATE_RANGE]+1,#duration(1,0,0,0))
),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "DATE"),{{"DATE", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"DATE_RANGE"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

If you applyed the code correctly, you will have a table like this:

[image]

Basically you have a record for every day in the sprint range.

Step 3: Now we can use this new "DATE" column to join both tables.

Go to the T_BACKLOG table and create a join between the tables. Then expand the table to get the "NAME" column. You can use the following code:

```
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"CREATION_DATE"}, R_SPRINT, {"DATE"}, "R_SPRINT", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded R_SPRINT" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "R_SPRINT", {"NAME"}, {"R_SPRINT.NAME"})
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Augustin Palacios. I tried your solution and it works perfectly :) Then I also adapated this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55649635/dax-categorise-event-using-dates-from-another-table?rq=1 , that works too.